# Matlab fast neighborhood operation

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a Problem. I have a Matrix *A* with integer values between 0 and 5.
for example like:

```
x=randi(5,10,10)
```

Now I want to call a filter, size 3x3, which gives me the the most common value

I have tried 2 solutions:

```
fun = @(z) mode(z(:));
y1 = nlfilter(x,[3 3],fun);
```

which takes very long...

and

```
y2 = colfilt(x,[3 3],'sliding',@mode);
```

which also takes long.
I have some really big matrices and both solutions take a long time.
Is there any faster way?

Comment: A mode filter will always be slow since it has to histogram the values then look for the most common value - so you end up with multiple passes through our data. Implemented in "vanilla matlab" that is very slow. You may be *much* faster by writing a small `mex` routine for yourself - it's quite an easy problem to get started with. Do you need any pointers?

Comment: Hmm... I never wrote a mex routine... Do you know a simple example that I can take as a sample? It would be easier for me to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 to @Floris for the excellent suggestion to use [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html). It's very fast. You can do a bit better though. `hist` is based on [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html), which can be used instead. `histc` is a compiled function, i.e., not written in Matlab, which is why the solution is much faster.

Here's a small function that attempts to generalize what @Floris did (also that solution returns a vector rather than the desired matrix) and achieve what you're doing with `nlfilter` and [`colfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html). It doesn't require that the input have particular dimensions and uses [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) to efficiently rearrange the data. In fact, the the first three lines and the call to `im2col` are virtually identical to what `colfit` does in your case.

```
function a=intmodefilt(a,nhood)
[ma,na] = size(a);
aa(ma+nhood(1)-1,na+nhood(2)-1) = 0;
aa(floor((nhood(1)-1)/2)+(1:ma),floor((nhood(2)-1)/2)+(1:na)) = a;
[~,a(:)] = max(histc(im2col(aa,nhood,'sliding'),min(a(:))-1:max(a(:))));
a = a-1;
```

Usage:

```
x = randi(5,10,10);
y3 = intmodefilt(x,[3 3]);
```

For large arrays, this is over 75 times faster than `colfilt` on my machine. Replacing `hist` with `histc` is responsible for a factor of two speedup. There is of course no input checking so the function assumes that `a` is all integers, etc.

Lastly, note that [`randi(IMAX,N,N)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) returns values in the range `1:IMAX`, not `0:IMAX` as you seem to state.

Comment: wow this is awesome. I just had to change a=a-1 to a=a-2 whatever. now its exactly what I want. It is 50 times faster than colfilt :) tomorrow I will try to check the code to improve my skills

Comment: The last line of the function, `a = a-1;`, converts the second output argument of `max` from a 1-based index to a 0-based index. If `min(a(:)) = 1`, this sets the borders of the output matrix to be 0 and the values to range from `1` to `max(a(:))` (`1` to `5` in your example). Using `a = a-2;` would then shift the inner part of the matrix to range from `0` to `4` in your example case.

Comment: Yes thx I got it :). It's really impressive. I learned alot today

Comment: @horchler thanks for the interesting solution! I was wondering how to do the re-arrangement based on circular neighborhoods? For instance, the neighborhood is now given by a circle, for which you have the radius? How can you put into the columns the pixels inside each sliding circle? I posted this question here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750989/matlab-efficient-computation-of-local-histograms-within-circular-neighboorhoods

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion would be to reshape your array so each 3x3 block becomes a column vector. If your initial array dimensions are divisible by 3, this is simple. If they don't, you need to work a little bit harder. And you need to repeat this nine times, starting at different offsets into the matrix - I will leave that as an exercise.

Here is some code that shows the basic idea (using only functions available in FreeMat - I don't have Matlab on my machine at home...):

```
N = 100;
A = randi(0,5*ones(3*N,3*N));
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A,[3 N 3 N]),[1 3 2 4]), [ 9 N*N]);
hh = hist(B, 0:5); % histogram of each 3x3 block: bin with largest value is the mode
[mm mi] = max(hh); % mi will contain bin with largest value
figure; hist(B(:),0:5); title 'histogram of B'; % flat, as expected
figure; hist(mi-1, 0:5); title 'histogram of mi' % not flat?...
```

Here are the plots:
[image]
[image]

The strange thing, when you run this code, is that the distribution of `mi` is not flat, but skewed towards smaller values. When you inspect the histograms, you will see that is because you will frequently have more than one bin with the "max" value in it. In that case, you get the first bin with the max number. This is obviously going to skew your results badly; something to think about. A much better filter might be a median filter - the one that has equal numbers of neighboring pixels above and below. That has a unique solution (while `mode` can have up to four values, for nine pixels - namely, four bins with two values each).

Something to think about.

Can't show you a `mex` example today (wrong computer); but there are ample good examples on the Mathworks website (and all over the web) that are quite easy to follow. See for example http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/

Comment: Thx for your help. The suggestion with resharp the array is somthing I must try and see if its faster than colfilt... I also thought about using median filter but I don't think it is the right solution for me... I also try to solve it with mex if it is not do difficult. Thx again :)

Comment: @Floris, thanks for your post! how can we reshape the data, but now based on circular neighborhoods? The circular neighborhoods are given by its `radius`. I'm trying to solve the question posted here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750989/matlab-efficient-computation-of-local-histograms-within-circular-neighboorhoods

Comment: @Tin - interesting question. I suspect you can create a vector of "neighbor offsets" once; see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462711/get-the-neighbors-of-a-matrix-element/21464505#21464505 for some details. If that doesn't help leave another comment and I will try to take a look.