# Get the neighbors of a matrix element

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix and for each element I want to get the index of its surrounding elements. All these results have to be stored into a matrix in the following way. Each row of the matrix corresponds to a matrix element and each of the columns of this matrix contain s the neighbor indexes. For example, for a 4x4 matrix we will get a 16x8 result array. Some of the matrix elements do not have 8 neighbors.

There is an example, I think it is working, I there any way to avoid for loop?:

```
ElementNeighbors = [];
for n = 1:numel(Matrix)
    NeighborsMask = [ n-1 n+1 n+size(matrix,1) n-size(Matrix,1) n-size(Matrix,1)-1 n-size(Matrix,1)+1 ...
        n+size(Matrix,1)-1 n+size(Matrix,1)+1 ];

    ElementNeighbors = [ElementNeighbors ; NeighborsMask ];
end
ElementNeighbors (ElementNeighbors ==0|ElementNeighbors <0) = NaN;
```

Comment: I don't understand the description of the desired output. Can you give an example line?

Comment: There are solutions for this problem all over (e.g., [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/25/neighbor-indexing-2/)). What about the elements on the edge of the matrix that have fewer than eight neighbors?

Comment: That I was thinking about, a mask. For the border elements there will not be 8 neighbors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the linear indices of a matrix M(n,m), you can convince yourself that the top left neighbor of element `M(i,j) = M(i-1, j-1) = M(i-1 + n * (j-2))`

In "linear index" space that means the offset of this element is

```
-n-1
```

Doing this for all other locations, we find

```
-n-1 | -1 | n-1
-n   |  x | n    => [-n-1, -n, -n+1, -1, +1, +n-1, +n, +n+1]
-n+1 | +1 | n+1
```

Thus you can create a vector offset with the above values (replacing n with the first dimension). For example, if M is (5x4), then

```
offset = [-6 -5 -4 -1 1 4 5 6];
```

You then create all the indices:

```
indices = bsxfun(@plus, (1:m*n), offset(:));
```

bsxfun is a cool shorthand for "do this function on these elements; where one element has a singleton dimension and the other doesn't, expand accordingly". You could do the same with repmat, but that creates unnecessary intermediate matrices (which can sometimes be very large).

That command will create a `(8 x m*n)` matrix of indices of all 8 neighbors, including ones that may not really be the neighbors... something you need to fix.

Several possible approaches:

- pad the matrix before you start
- don't care about wrapping, and just get rid of the elements that fall off the edge
- create a mask for all the ones that are "off the edge".

I prefer the latter. "Off the edge" means:

- going up in the top row
- going left in the left column
- going down in the bottom row
- going right in the right column

In each of these four cases there are 3 indices that are 'invalid'. Their position in the above matrix can be determined as follows:

```
mask = zeros(size(M));
mask(:,1) = 1;
left = find(mask == 1);
mask(:,end) = 2;
right = find(mask == 2);
mask(1,:) = 3;
top = find(mask == 3);
mask(end,:) = 4;
bottom = find(mask == 4);

edgeMask = ones(8,m*n);
edgeMask(1:3, top) = 0;
edgeMask([1 4 6], left) = 0;
edgeMask([3 5 8], right) = 0;
edgeMask(6:8, bottom) = 0;
```

Now you have everything you need - all the indices, and the "invalid" ones. Without loops.

If you were feeling ambitious you could turn this into a cell array but it will be slower than using the full array + mask. For example if you want to find the average of all the neighbors of a value, you can do

```
meanNeighbor = reshape(sum(M(indices).*edgeMask, 1)./sum(edgeMask, 1), size(M));
```

**EDIT** re-reading your question I see you wanted a M*N, 8 dimension. My code is transposed. I'm sure you can figure out how to adapt it...

**ATTRIBUTION** @Tin helpfully suggested many great edits to the above post, but they were rejected in the review process. I cannot totally undo that injustice - but would like to record my thanks here.

**EXTENDING TO DIFFERENT REGIONS AND MULTIPLE DIMENSIONS**

If you have an N-dimensional image matrix M, you could find the neighbors as follows:

```
temp = zeros(size(M));
temp(1:3,1:3,1:3) = 1;
temp(2,2,2) = 2;
offsets = find(temp==1) - find(temp==2);
```

If you want a region that is a certain radius in size, you could do

```
sz = size(M);
[xx yy zz] = meshgrid(1:sz(1), 1:sz(2), 1:sz(3));
center = round(sz/2);
rr = sqrt((xx - center(1)).^2 + (yy - center(2)).^2 + (zz - center(3)).^2);
offsets = find(rr < radius) - find(rr < 0.001);
```

You can probably figure out how to deal with the problem of edges along the lines shown earlier for the 2D case.

Untested - please see if you notice any problems with the above.

Comment: In the `M(i-1 + n * (j-2))` why `j-2` and not `j-1`?

Comment: Why in the "linear index" space the offset is `-n-1` and not just `n`? Also, why "replacing n with the second dimension" and not with the first dimension? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - you are right; that should have been "first dimension". I updated the answer. As for the `j-2` - it is really `(j-1) - 1` (top left corner = one to the left, and one row above.).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will mark your post as the answer as soon as I read a all of and maybe ask a few more things. Thanks again.

Comment: @Thoth - feel free to ask. I wrote this without having Matlab open so there could be typos. Test it!

Comment: Could you please explain a little more the last step of `edgemask`? You initialize `edgemask to zero` and again you assign values to zero. Also the indexes, i.e., `top`,`left`, etc. are we sure that are placed correctly?Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I initialize `edgeMask` to all ones, not zeros!

Comment: I think there is problem with the indexing in `edgeMask`. For example, wouldn't be more preferable to have `edgeMask(1:3, left) = 0;` according to the mask defined at the beggining?

Comment: @thoth - I think you are right. Sorry about delayed reply I was in a plane... Yes this needs a bit of cleaning up. Can you do it?

Comment: I have made the changes in my code but in the post I think I can not do it.

Comment: Ok I think it is fine now. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Floris, thanks for the illustration. I was not able to completely understand how did you got the `linear index space`? I was able tough to understand how you computed the `top left neighbor` linear index. Furthermore, I think, in your `bsxfun(@add,...` it should be `bsxfun(@plus,...`, right? Also for the `top row` and `bottom row` in your `mask`, you wrote `mark` instead of `mask` => `mark(1,:) = 3;` and `mark(end,:) = 4;`. Guess this is a misspelling, right?

Comment: @Tin - yes good catch on those typos. Regarding "linear index space" - in a 2D matrix `A=ones(3,2)`, elements are stored in the order (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (1,2), (2,2),(3,2). You can access `A(1,2)` as `A(4)` in the above example.

Comment: @Floris, thanks. I know that we can access matrices by linear indexes. I didn't get the part you were mentioning concerning: [`-n-1, -n, ..., n+1`].

Comment: @Tin that is "how many steps you need to go forward / back in the linear index space to reach the various neighbors".

Comment: @Now, I see, you were referring to the `8-neighborhood` ;-) It's more clear now. I edited your original post, hope it's ok for you so ;-) If you've the time, any feedback on my post, will be appreciated :-) => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750989/matlab-efficient-computation-of-local-histograms-within-circular-neighboorhoods

Comment: @Tin appreciate the edits you made - they were "rejected" in the review process; something I could not undo with the click of a button. So I re-applied your edits as best I could and thanks. I will take another look at your other post later today; I think the same thing can be done with just a minor change - computing the neighborhood offset vector rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: By the way, could you generalize the computation of the offset to the n-dimensional case instead of merely 2D?