# Mode filter for large matrices

Tags: matlab, filtering, mode, large-data

I am trying to filter some 4672 by 3001 matrices with values of 0 and 1 by finding the most common value in a given window size. I.e. finding the mode in a window around each pixel. A solution is to use

```
colfilt(A,[3 3],'sliding',@mode)
```

The below link shows a solution that is very much faster for a window size of [3 3].

[Matlab fast neighborhood operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871203/matlab-fast-neighborhood-operation/16877316#16877316?newreg=1f8eacd9f3604569b8c2a8e14d4684a6)

However, when I try to increase the window size (say to [9 9]) this solution becomes very slow.

Is there an alternative to do the filtering with a larger window size?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a matrix of zeros and ones, and you want to know, within each sliding block, if there are more zeros or more ones. Let `m` and `n` denote the number rows and columns per block.

The following does what you want using [`conv2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html). It essentially computes the 2D convolution with the kernel `ones(m,n)`, which gives the sum of all values within each block. That sum is compared to the threshold `m*n/2` to know if in that block there were more zeros or ones.

Since the convolution kernel `ones(m,n)` is **separable**, the 2D convolution can be replaced by a convolution with the column vector `ones(m,1)` followed by a convolution with the row vector `ones(1,n)`. This results in [faster code](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/).

```
A = randi(2,7,7)-1;                             %// example matrix with zeros and ones
m = 3;                                          %// number of rows in a block 
n = 2;                                          %// number of cols in a block
B = conv2(ones(m,1),ones(1,n),A,'same')>m*n/2;  %// result
```

**In case of a tie** this produces a `0` result. To produce `1` instead, change `>` into `>=`.

Also, you might want to change `'same'` into `'valid'` to **consider only full blocks**.

Compared to `colfilt`, this gives a significant speed gain:

```
>> A = randi(2,4672,3001)-1;
>> m = 3; n = 3;
>> tic, B1 = colfilt(A,[m n],'sliding',@mode); toc
Elapsed time is 13.874891 seconds.
>> tic, B2 = conv2(ones(m,1),ones(1,n),A,'same')>m*n/2; toc
Elapsed time is 0.206820 seconds.
>> all(all(B1==B2))
ans =
     1
```

Comment: OMG. This works awesome. The speed also seems to not significantly increase with the window size. Perfect!